# Insertion of logo on whole of th right side in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I am new in the  latex beamer presentation. I am try to insert a logo that span the whole right side  as  show below. Please help me with a code to have something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the `headline` template of the `split theme`. You can set your custom header image via

```
\newcommand\headerimage{<path to image>}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\newcommand\headerimage{example-image-a}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \includegraphics[width=.5\paperwidth,height=\@tempdimb]{\headerimage}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\frame{\frametitle{\secname}}
\section{Background Information}
\frame{\frametitle{\secname}}
\section{The Important Things}
\frame{\frametitle{\secname}}
\section{Analysis of the Work}
\frame{\frametitle{\secname}}
\section{Conclusion}
\frame{\frametitle{\secname}}
\end{document}
```

> [image]